# Emacs and Skim not in Sync fails to open

Tags: emacs, latex

New to posting to Stack Overflow, but I'll ask away. I have been having issues linking up Emacs with Skim.  Using tex-mode.

I have used code that has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899845/emacs-synctex-skim-how-to-correctly-set-up-syncronization-none-of-the-exi?newreg=d12ae88c5abb4ec0a6f176104f10b5b9) on the site that shows how to do it.

Which does compile and shows output. Produces an .aux .log and .pdf file

But fails to preview using C-c C-v.  It does not open up skim and outputs an error that says.

> "No appropriate `.dvi' file could be found"

from my understanding this snippet of code should be linking up C-c C-v, which is same to tex-view.

`(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
 (setq TeX-view-program-list
     '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))`

I am curious where this issue may be coming from, current emacs version is 24.5.1 
using Tex Live 2014

### Found Solution to my Problem:

I found that regular tex-mode pre-installed by emacs was not complete, and that I need to download auctex, from the packages listed in el-get or melpa to get it to work properly.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119645/26911

Comment: What is Skim? Is [this it](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Chris  Yes, that is the right Skim, it's a PDF viewer for mac OS X.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you, I will read more into it and see if I can tweak it to my fitting.